# Why am I getting SSL issues inside docker with pip

Tags: python, docker, ssl, pip

I am facing issues lately with using `pip` while building a `docker` image. The base OS is ubuntu 18.04 and the error is as below

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: DECRYPTION_FAILED_OR_BAD_RECORD_MAC] decryption failed or bad record mac (_ssl.c:852)'),)': /simple/pip/
Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: DECRYPTION_FAILED_OR_BAD_RECORD_MAC] decryption failed or bad record mac (_ssl.c:852)'),)': /simple/pip/
Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: DECRYPTION_FAILED_OR_BAD_RECORD_MAC] decryption failed or bad record mac (_ssl.c:852)'),)': /simple/pip/
Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: DECRYPTION_FAILED_OR_BAD_RECORD_MAC] decryption failed or bad record mac (_ssl.c:852)'),)': /simple/pip/
Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: DECRYPTION_FAILED_OR_BAD_RECORD_MAC] decryption failed or bad record mac (_ssl.c:852)'),)': /simple/pip/
```

The same works in host OS with out issues. The docker version is Docker version 19.03.3, build a872fc2f86

Some of the troubeshooting I have done currently.

1. Adding DNS to `/etc/docker/daemon.json`
2. Restarting docker engine
3. Running with `pip --trusted-host pypi.org install -U pip`
4. Adding certificate and updating ca

Inspite of all the troubleshooting the issue still persists. Is there anyother way to get this working.

PS : This just started to happen from yesterday and there were no issues earlier.

Comment: What is the base image used in Dockerfile? Looks like the base image does not have relevant SSL packages to decrypt the certificates when presented by the source.

Comment: The base image is ubuntu

Answer (score 2):

try to add the cacert for Ubuntu in your Dockerfile:

```
RUN wget -P /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/cacert.org http://www.cacert.org/certs/root.crt http://www.cacert.org/certs/class3.crt

RUN update-ca-certificates
```

if that does not help you may see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51427372/pip-install-ssl-error)